# Remove Column From Grid Menu in UI Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have two columns that I have its visibility to false. They are called $$TreeLevel and Instrument. I want to keep them hidden at all times so I am trying to remove them from the Grid Menu hamburger drop down. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom menu feature of UI grid, http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu

Comment: This doesn't work because I am trying to remove the option from the hamburger menu. Not each specific column's menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS provides option to add custom fields to the UI Grid Menu. The 2 ways to do that are

1) gridCustomMenu function -> Used within the onRegisterApi function of the UI Grid.
2) Functions call present in the gridApi.core feature

gridApi.core has 2 primary functions -

a) gridApi.core.addToGridMenu(grid,items), where items is an array which comprises of a JSON object with certain properties that you want to add.
Ex - gridApi.core.addToGridMenu(grid, [{title: 'ABC', order: 10}]);

b) gridApi.core.removeFromGridMenu() -> I think you need to make use of this function to remove your custom entries from the UI Grid Dropdown!